# c++ why cannot call overloaded() with-> using a pointer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

just out of curiosity. If it is allowed to call a function using -> by a pointer, why not calling operator() by -> ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct point {
   int x;
   int y;
   void show() {cout<< x <<" : "<< y <<endl;}
   void operator()() {cout<< x <<" : "<< y <<endl;}
};

int main()
{
   point p;
   p.x=1; p.y=2;
   p();

   point* ptr = &p;
   ptr->show();
   (*ptr)();    // ok
   ptr->();     // error
   return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:20:9: error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
ptr->();
```

I know ptr->func() is equivalent to (*ptr).func(), so can an overloaded operator be called directly from pointer, without dereferencing. What is the internal difference between a function and an overloaded operator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `ptr->()`, write `ptr->operator()()`.

Comment: as a side note, in C++ you can overload the `->` operator too